# Wildfly 29 on Docker: Failed to load module org.jboss.as.jsr77 error

Tags: docker, wildfly

I have the problem that when trying to start my docker container with Wildfly 29 I get this error:

*Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: WFLYCTL0083: Failed to load module org.jboss.as.jsr77
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: WFLYCTL0309: Legacy extension 'org.jboss.as.jsr77' is not supported on servers running this version. The extension is only supported for use by hosts running a previous release in a mixed-version managed domain*

I am using the version "29.0.1.Final-jdk11" but the same thing happens to me with any version 29, however if I use, for example, version 26.1.1.Final wildfly rises without problems.

I tried to remove the extension, using a cli command:

*/extension=org.jboss.as.jsr77:remove()*

however I get this error:

*"WFLYCTL0216: Manage Resource '[("extension" => "org.jboss.as.jsr77")]' not found"*

Any ideas that can help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: That extension has been removed. Are you attempting to migrate an older configuration?

Comment: Hi James, no, I'm just using Wildfly image 29.0.1:

FROM quay.io/wildfly/wildfly:29.0.1.Final-jdk11

Comment: Can you share your configuration/Dockerfile at all? Or do you have a way to reproduce it, I don't seem to be able to reproduce it.